# Random permutation and isolated points on the line

Tags: probability, reference-request, permutations

Let $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$ be the (ordered) set of the $n$ first integers, and $\mathcal{S}_n$ denote the set of permutations of $[n]$. Let $1\leq k \leq \frac{n}{4}$ be an integer.

If I draw uniformly at random a permutation $\pi\in\mathcal{S}_n$, I'd like to bound the probability that $\pi(1),\pi(2),\dots,\pi(k)$ are clustered in at most (say) $k/4$ different intervals... that is, I'd like to know what the probability is that a random permutation puts this $k$ points in no more than $m$ "chunks", where $m=k/4$ or $k/100$ for instance.

I've tried to think about it for a short while, but even formulating the question in terms I could use is not obvious. For instance, even to compute the expected number of this chunks seems to escape me -- I can't see how to phrase it in terms of random variables nice enough to analyze.

(also, I'm not even sure whether this is not a very common or well-understood question, for which I only lack the proper term or name -- hence the "reference-request" tag)

PS: this is an open-ended research question, for a lemma I'd need or at least would like to have.

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, if we had say $\pi(1)=2$, $\pi(4)=3$, and $\pi(k)=4$, then this would compromise 1 "chunk"?

Comment: $\{2,3,4\}$ would be one chunk; the total number of chunks would depend on the other values for $\pi(i)$, $i\in [k]\setminus\{1,4,k\}$. Basically, once you apply $\pi$to $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, you end up with $k$ points in $[n]$ -- call this set $S_\pi$. The minimum number of intervals from $S_\pi$ needed to cover $S_\pi$ (i.e., covering these $k$ points by intervals without including any other point) would be the number of "chunks."

Comment: Right. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a seemingly very loose bound, but which would probably be enough for my goals:

Let $X_1,\dots, X_{n-1}$ be the $n-1$ (identically distributed, but non-independent) indicator random variables defined as follows. $X_i$ is $1$ if $\pi^{-1}(i) \leq k$, but $\pi^{-1}(i+1)  > k$ (that is, one of the $k$ "good" points ends up on $i$, but one of the $n-k$ "bad points" ends up on $i+1$).

Let $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i$ be their sum: note that $X$ is a lower bound on the number of clusters, up to an additive one ($X$ counts the number of "right borders," and may only be off if the last cluster-interval ends at $n$). Moreover,

$$\mathbb{E} X_i = \frac{k}{n}\cdot \frac{n-k}{n-1} \tag{$\dagger$}$$
so that
$$
\mathbb{E} X = k\cdot \frac{n-k}{n} = k\left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)
$$
by linearity. If we define $Y = k-X \geq 0$ (with $\mathbb{E} Y = \frac{k^2}{n}$)

Then, by Markov's inequality, 
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ X \leq \frac{k}{10} \} = \mathbb{P}\{ Y \geq \frac{9k}{10} \}
\leq \frac{\mathbb{E} Y}{9k/10} = \frac{k/n}{9/10} = \frac{10}{9}\frac{k}{n}
$$
which gives a non-trivial bound for $k < \frac{9n}{10}$.

This looks correct to me, although (early morning) I'll have to check $(\dagger)$.